# In Kotlin, how do I read the entire contents of an InputStream into a String?

Tags: inputstream, kotlin

I recently saw code for reading entire contents of an `InputStream` into a String in Kotlin, such as:

```kotlin
// input is of type InputStream
val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
input.use { it.copyTo(baos) }
val inputAsString = baos.toString()
```

And also:

```kotlin
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(input))
try {
    val results = StringBuilder()
    while (true) { 
        val line = reader.readLine()
        if (line == null) break
        results.append(line) 
    }
    val inputAsString = results.toString()
} finally {
    reader.close()
}
```

And even this that looks smoother since it auto-closes the `InputStream`:

```kotlin
val inputString = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(input)).useLines { lines ->
    val results = StringBuilder()
    lines.forEach { results.append(it) }
    results.toString()
}
```

Or slight variation on that one:

```kotlin
val results = StringBuilder()
BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(input)).forEachLine { results.append(it) }
val resultsAsString = results.toString()
```

Then this functional fold thingy:

```kotlin
val inputString = input.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
    lines.fold(StringBuilder()) { buff, line -> buff.append(line) }.toString()
}
```

Or a **bad** variation which doesn't close the `InputStream`:

```kotlin
val inputString = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(input))
        .lineSequence()
        .fold(StringBuilder()) { buff, line -> buff.append(line) }
        .toString()
```

But they are all clunky and I keep finding newer and different versions of the same... and some of them never even close the `InputStream`.  What is a non-clunky (idiomatic) way to read the `InputStream`?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin topics are present in SO.*

Comment: I know its already perfectly answered but here is a perfectly described article from baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/inputstream-to-string :)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Kotlin has a specific extension just for this purpose.

**The simplest:**

```
val inputAsString = input.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }  // defaults to UTF-8
```

And in this example, you could decide between `bufferedReader()` or just `reader()`.  The call to the function [`Closeable.use()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) will automatically close the input at the end of the lambda's execution.

**Further reading:**

If you do this type of thing a lot, you could write this as an extension function:

```
fun InputStream.readTextAndClose(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): String {
    return this.bufferedReader(charset).use { it.readText() }
}
```

Which you could then call easily as:

```
val inputAsString = input.readTextAndClose()  // defaults to UTF-8
```

On a side note, all Kotlin extension functions that require knowing the `charset` already default to `UTF-8`, so if you require a different encoding you need to adjust the code above in calls to include encoding for `reader(charset)` or `bufferedReader(charset)`.

**Warning:** You might see examples that are shorter:

```
val inputAsString = input.reader().readText()
```

But these **do not close the stream**.  Make sure you check the [API documentation for all of the IO functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html) you use to be sure which ones close and which do not.  Usually, if they include the word `use` (such as `useLines()` or `use()`) they close the stream after.  An exception is that [`File.readText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html) differs from [`Reader.readText()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/read-text.html) in that the former does not leave anything open and the latter does indeed require an explicit close.

**See also:**  [Kotlin IO related extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html)

Comment: I think "readText" would be a better name than "useText" for the extension function you propose. When I read "useText" I expect a function like `use` or `useLines` which executes a block function on what is being "used". e.g. `inputStream.useText { text -> ... }` On the other hand, when I read "readText" I expect a function which returns the text: `val inputAsString = inputStream.readText()`.

Comment: True, but readText already has the wrong meaning, so wanted to signify it was more like the `use` functions in that regard. at least in context of this Q&A.   maybe a new verb can be found...

Comment: @mfulton26 I went with `readTextAndClose()` for this example to avoid conflicting with `readText()` patterns of not closing, and with `use` patterns wanting a lambda, since I'm not trying to introduce a new stdlib function I don't want to do more than make a point about using extensions to save future labour.

Comment: @JaysonMinard why don't you mark this for answer? it's great though :-)

Comment: Since Kotlin 1.3, `readBytes` + String constructor is arguably simpler, but it is limited to 2GB so probably not worth recommending (hence this comment, rather than an answer): `inputStream.use { String(it.readBytes()) }`. Defaults to UTF-8, but you can also pass an encoding to the `String` constructor. Still, seems like using an `InputStreamReader` is a good habit if reading text, even when less than 2GB, which is probably most of the time.

Comment: This reads the entire content into memory defeating the point of using a stream in the first place.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman it is what was requested to read it into a string, and there are valid reasons for that.

Answer (score 4):

【**Method 1 | Manually Close Stream**】

```
private fun getFileText(uri: Uri):String {
    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!

    val bytes = inputStream.readBytes()        //see below

    val text = String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)    //specify charset

    inputStream.close()

    return text
}
```

- `inputStream.readBytes()` requires manually close the stream: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/read-bytes.html

---

【**Method 2 | Automatically Close Stream**】

```
private fun getFileText(uri: Uri): String {
    return contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.bufferedReader().use {it.readText() }
}
```

- You can specify the charset inside `bufferedReader()`, default is `UTF-8`:
  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/buffered-reader.html
- `bufferedReader()` is an upgrade version of `reader()`, it is more versatile:
  [How exactly does bufferedReader() work in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510968/how-exactly-does-bufferedreader-work-in-kotlin)
- `use()` can automatically close the stream when the block is done:
  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html

Comment: to improve the answer, please give some narrative explaining how this works

Comment: Why do you mix `readBytes` and `readText` between your examples? Closing the stream automatically is handled by `use`, the choice of `BufferedReader`/`readText` and `readBytes` is not relevant to that. The second example is also the same as the example at the top of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

An example that reads contents of an InputStream to a String

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.charset.Charset

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val file = File("input"+File.separator+"contents.txt")
    var ins:InputStream = file.inputStream()
    var content = ins.readBytes().toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
    println(content)
}
```

For Reference - [Kotlin Read File](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/read-contents-of-a-file-in-kotlin/#inputstream)

Comment: Your example contains flaws: 1) For cross-platform paths you should use `Paths.get()` method. 2) For streams - try-resource feature (In kotlin: .use {})

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution works well when converting InputStream to string.

```
val convertedInputStream = String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: There is no `readAllBytes` method on `InputStream`. Maybe you meant `readBytes`? If so, then you also need to close the stream.