# How long String property can be in Kotlin?

Tags: android, base64, kotlin

I created simple `Base64Images` helper class which contains this body:

```
companion object{
  val ABSTRACT_COLORS = "[image encoded in base64]"
}
```

`ABSTRACT_COLORS` is actually a string which has 570438 characters.

During compilation I got:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate property ABSTRACT_COLORS
...
...
The root cause was thrown at: ByteVector.java:213 at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genFunctionOrProperty(MemberCodegen.java:205)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I thought I can store [2147483647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have) characters in a string.

Why is that?

I posted this image below. 
You can use [this tool](https://www.base64-image.de/) to generate base64.

Hint: editing this class or compiling the project freezes Android Studio.
I'd use some lightweight editor to edit and terminal to compile it.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a compilation bug. e.g. If the compiler is failing because it doesn't have enough memory allocated then the exception thrown should state such (which it doesn't). I suggest reporting the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT. You might search online for a way to increase the kotlin compiler's allocated memory or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in a comment by @mfulton26 that something is going on with the compiler when loading the string.  A crash bug that should be reported to [Kotlin issue tracker](http://kotl.in/issue).

As a work-around you can add this as a file in your `src/main/resources` directory and loading the string dynamically either as a `String` or as `ByteArray`.

For example, if the file was `src/main/resources/abstract-colors.txt` you could [read the entire file into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500045/in-kotlin-how-do-i-read-the-entire-contents-of-an-inputstream-into-a-string#39500046):

```
val ABSTRACT_COLORS = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/abstract-colors.txt")
                               .bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

If you did not need it to be base64 encoded, you could store the image as binary and read it into an `ByteArray`.

```
val ABSTRACT_COLORS = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/abstract-colors.jpg")
                               .use { it.readBytes() }
```

Comment: the string has less than 0,5MB not 0.5GB ;) I know i can load the content from file... but still it would be nice to have it at compilation time.

Comment: @mklimek edited and leaving answer (other people in the future may need this work around, the answer is for the community as well)

Comment: There is much better solution. Put files to assets folder (not in the resources) and use `assets.open("jpeg_base64.txt").bufferedReader().readText()`