# How to parse JSON from an url using Kotlin on Android?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I've been trying to parse JSON from an url for hours now but I'm too stupid I guess
I have tried

```
val result = URL("http://date.jsontest.com/").readText()
```

but it crashes

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: date.jsontest.com

I have tried Klaxon's library

```
fun parse(name: String) : Any? {    
    val cls = Parser::class.java
    return cls.getResourceAsStream(name)?.let { 
        inputStream -> return Parser().parse(inputStream)
    }
}    
val obj = parse("http://date.jsontest.com/") as JsonObject
```

but it also crashes

> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.beust.klaxon.JsonObject

Can someone please write in Kotlin the simpliest way to parse data from this link http://date.jsontest.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883593/how-to-read-json-from-url-using-kotlin-android/44883989#44883989 answers your question.

Comment: what am I supposed to do with this ?...

Comment: can you post your stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say why you are getting an error. Since this line is correct and working.

```
val result = URL("http://date.jsontest.com/").readText()
```

For the parse method. It does not work, becase it expects path to a JSON file but is getting a URL String.

Simplest example using Klaxon would be this.

```
val result = URL("http://date.jsontest.com/").readText()
val parser: Parser = Parser()
val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(result)
val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
println("Time : ${json.string("time")}, Since epoch : ${json.long("milliseconds_since_epoch")}, Date : ${json.string("date")}, ")
```