# Android Kotlin (beginner) - using File() with Uri returned from ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm very new to both Android and Kotlin/Java. I don't understand why my `File()` method gets the error:

> none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

I thought that what I have put should return the Uri obtained from the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and that this should be enough to construct the File object. I'm trying to make an app that will load a txt file and display it. I'm hoping it's a really simple mistake somewhere:

```
fun showFileDialog() {
    val fileintent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    fileintent.setType("text/plain")
    fileintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(fileintent, FILE_SELECT_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedfile = File(data!!.data)
        val readData = FileInputStream(selectedfile).bufferedReader().use { it.readText
            textView.text = readData
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the rest of the posted code works either, but this error will not let me build it to test it. TIA for any help/pointers

RESOLVED:

The first answer explained why I was getting the error (hence, answering my question)

After getting help from second answer and comment below, (and more searching on SO; see links below) I changed my last 3 lines of code to:

```
val input: InputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data!!.data)
val inputAsString = input.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
textView.setText(inputAsString)
```

and this is working well. Thank you!

LINKS:

[Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri)

[In Kotlin, how do I read the entire contents of an InputStream into a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500045/in-kotlin-how-do-i-read-the-entire-contents-of-an-inputstream-into-a-string)

Comment: You are not supposed to use the File class for an uri obtained by ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Nor are you supposed to deduce a file path from that uri to use the File class on it. Instead you should directly open an inputstream for the obtained uri if you want to read it contents.

Comment: Thank you @greenapps. I changed to reflect this and it's working well. getContentResolver().openInputStream() seems to accept the android.Uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't comment on the rest of your code, `data!!.data` [returns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()) a `android.Uri` and `File` takes a [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String))[1].

You have to convert your Uri to a filename: something like `File(data!!data.getPath());` [2]

[1]. It also takes a URI, but that's a Java.net.URI, rather  than an Android.Uri.

[2]. You should still make sure that you're getting a Uri which points to a path on the filesystem. You may also have to do something like [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-get-real-file-path-from-android-uri/).

Comment: Thank you, especially for note [1]. I didn't realise there was this distinction in the URIs

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use the File class for an uri obtained by `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Nor are you supposed to deduce a file path from that uri to use the File class on it.

Instead you should directly open an inputstream for the obtained uri if you want to read it contents.

Comment: I want to be able to accept both answers because this is a very helpful improvement

Comment: Its no inprovement. In fact its the only answer/solution to your problem.