# How exactly does bufferedReader() work in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

So I'm trying to read data from a `.json` file in my Android project:

```
val file = context.assets.open("myfile.json").bufferedReader().readText()
```

This works fine and successfully prints out my `.json` file as one `String`.

However I want to know what exactly is `bufferedReader()` and why `.readText()` can't be called directly on the opened `.json` file.

PS: `readText()` returns a `String`. However:

`val json2: JSONObject = JSONObject("mystring")` returns:

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value mystring of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

How does this make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `readText` function is defined as an extension on `Reader`:

```
public fun Reader.readText(): String {
    val buffer = StringWriter()
    copyTo(buffer)
    return buffer.toString()
}
```

An `InputStream` isn't a `Reader`, so you have to transform it into some `Reader`:

```
public inline fun InputStream.reader(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): InputStreamReader = 
    InputStreamReader(this, charset)
```

You can use the reader as a buffered reader with the alternative `bufferedReader` function:

```
public inline fun InputStream.bufferedReader(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): BufferedReader = 
    reader(charset).buffered()
```

`Reader` and also [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) are part of the Java standard library and the buffered version is described like this:

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to
>   provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.
>
> In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream.  It is
>    therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader whose read()
>    operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders...

It basically wraps a `Reader` and adds support for reading single lines etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
val file = context.assets.open("myfile.json").bufferedReader().readText()
```

Here is the code that do the same thing as above line.

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("myfile.json")
val reader = inputStream.bufferedReader()
val file = reader.readText()
```

Assume here is the content of `myfile.json`

```
{
    "os": "Android",
    "version": "KitKat",
    "codeName": 4.4
}
```

Let's go step by step

**Step 1:** The first line

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("myfile.json")
```

This will be return an [InputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream) object, which reads one byte or number of bytes from the json file. If you print the json file content in byte format on the screen, it will really hard for us (as programmers) to read.

**Step 2:** The second line

```
val reader = inputStream.bufferedReader()
```

This will create a [BufferedReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader) object, which read a character or a number of characters from the json file, but they have another useful method named [readLine()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader#readLine()), this method reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Let's modify the current code.

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("myfile.json")
val reader = inputStream.bufferedReader()

// Read line by line from reader until reach the end.
var line = reader.readLine()
while(line != null) {
    Log.i("TAG", line)
    line = reader.readLine()
}
```

Output:

```
I/TAG: {
I/TAG:     "os": "Android",
I/TAG:     "version": "KitKat",
I/TAG:     "codeName": 4.4
I/TAG: }
```

As we can see, they print 5 lines from the json file. But in some cases, we want to print all the json file as a String, that why we move to next step.

**Step 3:** The third line

```
val file = reader.readText()
```

This will reads the buffer reader completely as a String. You can write your own to do the same like.

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("myfile.json")
val reader = inputStream.bufferedReader()

val sb = StringBuffer()

var line = reader.readLine()
while(line != null) {
    Log.i("TAG", line)
    sb.append(line).append("\n")
    line = reader.readLine()
}

val file = sb.toString()

Log.i("TAG", file)
```

Output:

```
I/TAG: {
        "os": "Android",
        "version": "KitKat",
        "codeName": 4.4
}
```

This output is the same as `reader.readText()`.

**Conclusion:** BufferReader wraps an InputStream (or sub-classes of InputStream) inside them, then provide methods to read character-by-character instead of byte-by-byte in InputStream. In addition, they provide readLine() method, buffer data.

> InputStream (byte-by-byte) -> Reader (character-by-character)
>
> InputStream (byte-by-byte) -> BufferReader (character-by-character,
>   read line, buffer data).