# How to read json file from path using kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to open a file picker in android, select a json file then get the text from it. 
The app crashes after i select the file because it can not find the path.

I have tried adding external storage read / write permission and changing the path format

```
/// some Activity code
val myFileIntent=Intent()
.setType("*/*")
.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
startActivityForResult(myFileIntent,10)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val path = data!!.data.path
        val jsonContent = File(path).readText()
    }
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: Hi, this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129285/235354

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/reteta.json (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.readBytes(FileReadWrite.kt:63)
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.readText(FileReadWrite.kt:101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my final working code :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val path = data?.data
        val jsonSelectedFile =  contentResolver.openInputStream(path);
        val inputAsString = jsonSelectedFile.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Json: " +  inputAsString , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

And for calling :

```
 importJsonButton.setOnClickListener {
            val myFileIntent = Intent()
                .setType("*/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

            startActivityForResult(myFileIntent,10)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to open a file picker in android

That is not a file picker. That allows the user to choose a piece of content, which may or may not be a file.

> The app crashes after i select the file

You are not picking a file. You are picking a piece of content. That content is identified by a `Uri`, and the scheme of your `Uri` is `content`, not `file`.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. You can call `readText()` on that `InputStream` to read it in as text.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how could i implement that ?

Comment: This can not be done . You can not call readText() on that InputStream to read it in as text.

Comment: @TeodorRadu: Ah, sorry, I was mis-remembering. You need to convert the `InputStream` into a `BufferedReader`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500046/115145